# Рож-денный – допустим ли такой перенос?

Tags: орфография, морфология, морфемика, перенос

1. Допустимо ли переносить рож-денный?
2. Рож-денный и ро-жденный – равноправные варианты переноса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы. Правило.

§ 217. Группа неодинаковых согласных букв в середине слова, входящих в корень или образующих стык корня и суффикса, может быть разбита переносом любым образом, напр.: ***се-стра, сес-тра и сест-ра; це-нтральный, цен-тральный и цент-ральный; ро-ждение и рож-дение; де-тство, дет-ство, детс-тво и детст-во; шу-мный и шум-ный.***

См.: Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации.